# PHP: How to change foreach array index $key count to 1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a foreach loop with an array value, my problem is i need to make the value of $key starts with 1 instead of 0.

My code

```
if(isset($_POST['sp_criteria'])){
        $sp_criteria = $_POST['sp_criteria'];
        $sp_criterias = array();
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($sp_criteria as $key => $value) {
            $sp_criterias[$count] = $value;
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

And the output

```
[0] - 10 sp_criteria
[1] - 15 sp_criteria
[2] - 15sp_criteria
[3] - 20 sp_criteria
[4] - 25 sp_criteria
[5] - 15 sp_criteria
```

And how do i make it to like this?

```
[1] - 10 sp_criteria
[2] - 15 sp_criteria
[3] - 15sp_criteria
[4] - 20 sp_criteria
[5] - 25 sp_criteria
[6] - 15 sp_criteria
```

Comment: Just add 1 to the $key before you echo it out.

Comment: or use $count in your echo instead of $key.

Comment: Use `$count`, not `$key`, no?

Comment: you're outputting `$key`, which you EXPLICITLY set to `0` when you start the loop... so yeah, you'll get `0`.

Comment: i need the array key which is the $key to change to 1

Comment: Why? Arrays in PHP are zero-indexed so this is default, standard, expected behavior?

Comment: cuz i need to compare that indexes to my id in database so i need it to make 1 instead of 0

Comment: How are you outputting that array?

Answer (score 2):

just put in the foreach loop $key++;

Answer (score 1):

```
    echo $value." - ".(int)$key+1." sp_criteria<br/>";
```

If your keys are always numeric, you could use a simpler **for** loop instead of **foreach**.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go for ($key + 1) is there any particular reason:

```
if(isset($_POST['sp_criteria'])){
    $sp_criteria = $_POST['sp_criteria'];
    $sp_criterias = array();
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($sp_criteria as $key => $value) {
        $sp_criterias[$count] = $value;
        echo $value." - ".($key + 1)." sp_criteria<br/>";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(isset($_POST['sp_criteria'])){
        $sp_criteria = $_POST['sp_criteria'];
        $sp_criterias = array();
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($sp_criteria as $key => $value) {
            $sp_criterias[$count] = $value;
            echo $value." - ".$key." sp_criteria<br/>";
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['sp_criteria'])){
        $sp_criteria = $_POST['sp_criteria'];
        $sp_criterias = array();
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($sp_criteria as $key => $value) {
            $sp_criterias[$count] = $value;
            echo $value." - ". ( $key + 1 ) ." sp_criteria<br/>";
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can not modify the indices of your array. But you can unshift your array then unset the first item.

```
array_unshift($sp_criteria, '');
unset($sp_criteria[0]);
```

Or you can create an array which starts from 1 as below:

```
$sp_criteria = [1 => 'a', 'b', 'c'];
```

But I am not a fan of this way. Normally, an array starts from 0 and we should keep this consistent all the time. If some arrays start from 0 and others start from 1, it will be difficult for you to handle them. Sometimes you think the using array starts from 1 but actually it starts from 0. As a result, this may cause an unexpected bug.